# Scroll to Element Jquery not working on Chrome or Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, safari

I'm having some problems trying to implement this feature on a project I'm working on. Basically the objective is if the user clicks on the "Get Started" Button it will directly scroll on the specified element. The only problem is that it doesn't work on chrome or safari which is very weird and sometimes the website tends to flicker randomly whenever i click on it

Here is the website I'm working on

digitalspin.ph/create/index.html

**HTML**

```
<section class="get_started">
<div class="container_12">
    <div class="grid_12 relative">
        <h2 id="gs_button"><a href="#company_info"><span>Get<br/> Started</span></a></h2>
    </div>
</div>
</section>


<div class="content">
<div id="company_info" class="container_12">
    <h2 class="creative_spin_small">Creative Spin</h2>
    <div class="liquid-slider"  id="main-slider">
        <div class="slide1">
        <h2 class="title">Who We Are</h2>
        <div class="custom_column">
            <div class="message">
                <h3>turning</h3>
                <h4>your</h4>
                <h5>imagination</h5>
                <h6>into <span>reality</span></h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom_column">
        grid 6
        </div>
        </div>

        <div>
        <h2 class="title">What We Can Do</h2>
        <p>Proin nec turpis eget dolor dictum lacinia. Nullam nunc magna, tincidunt eu porta in, faucibus sed magna. Suspendisse laoreet ornare ullamcorper. Nulla in tortor nibh. Pellentesque sed est vitae odio vestibulum aliquet in nec leo.</p>
        </div>      

    </div>
</div>
<div class="social">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank" alt="Facebook">Facebook</a></li>
        <li id="social_twitter"><a href="#" target="_blank" alt="Twitter">Twitter</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#gs_button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: ($("#company_info").first().offset().top)
    }, 1200);
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried logging what's inside $("#company_info").first().offset().top?

Comment: I'm sorry i'm still new with javascript and jquery. What do mean you by logging in $("#company_info").first().offset().top?

Comment: $("#gs_button").click(function() { console.log( 'top', $("#company_info").first().offset().top ); });

Answer (score 0):

When you click on `heading gs_button` then `anchor tag` in `heading` also get `clicked`, so your `animate function` not works try to bind click event on `anchor` instead of `heading` like,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#gs_button a").click(function(e) {// bind anchor here
       $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: ($("#company_info").offset().top)
       }, 1200);
       e.preventDefault();// to prevent default working of anchor;
    });
});
```

Hope this works.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gE9x8/) check in `Firefox` and `Chrome`.

Comment: Hi i just tried solution. It works on mozilla but on chrome or safari it won't scroll down to the specified element. I just saw the demo in fiddle and i'm very confused why it wont work on chrome T_T

Comment: Demo is working in chrome and ff both. Try [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/gE9x8/1/)

Comment: Change the `jquery version` to `1.9.1` and try

Comment: Changed the jquery to 1.9.1 and still not working on chrome T_T

Comment: I tried removing the slider plugin if ever it has any conflict but no luck

Comment: Been trying to fix this problem for hours and still no luck and no fix. I even tried using a plugin.

Comment: then remove all other plugins, scripts. Use only `jquery` and then try above code

Comment: I managed to locate the problem regarding the scrollTo feature. It's because i have set the "HTML,Body" to overflow:hidden that is why it's not working on chrome nor in safari. Is there a way i can still hide the scrollbar and still make it work in chrome or in safari?

Answer (score 0):

The bug is in webkit's ability to animate the body. Instead, create a div just inside body and apply the animation to this instead...

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav>
            <a class="scroll-to-id" href="#" data-target="section1">Section 1</a>
            <a class="scroll-to-id" href="#" data-target="section2">Section 2</a>
        </nav>
        <section>
            <a id="section1">&nbsp;</a>
            <p>Some content<p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <a id="section2">&nbsp;</a>
            <p>Some more content<p>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Note:** In my personal experience, the ID could be just as effectively applied to the  tag instead of a redundant  and this still work ... I've only done it this way in this example because some users noted issues with targeting IDs higher up the DOM tree than this ... I couldn't personally recreate that problem, so hey, either way works!

Then style the wrapper element and body to behave correctly

```
body { position:relative; }

.wrapper { overflow:auto; position:absolute; top:0; height:100%; width:100%; }
```

Then the jQuery

```
$('.scroll-to-id').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = "#" + $(this).data('target');
    $('.wrapper').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 1500);
});
```